# Vue 3 dynamcially load async components

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I want to display a component depending on it's type. Let me explain.

I have multiple components that are similar to each other but depending on the given type they should display something different. With the `defineAsyncComponent` method I can import the components and use them easiliy. Example:

```
const CheckboxControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/CheckboxControl.vue'),
);
```

This works fine, but if I do this I have a ton of imported components. I don't want this. My approach is to wrap the `defineAsyncComponent` inside an arrow function like this:

```
const loadComponent = async (type: string) =>
  defineAsyncComponent(
    () =>
      import(
        `@/components/editor/controls/${type[0].toUpperCase()}${type.substring(
          1,
        )}Control.vue`
      ),
  );
```

In the template I am then able to render the component like this `<component :is="renderComponent(control.type)" />`

But this gives me the following warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function.
```

Awaiting the `defineAsyncComponent` method doesn't solve the issue.

What am I doing wrong? How can I dynamically import these components?

#### Update

Here are all the possibilities that can be inside the `control.type` attribute:

- checkbox
- date
- email
- number
- radio
- range
- select
- textarea
- text

#### Update 2

This is my current code that is working:

```
const CheckboxControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/CheckboxControl.vue'),
);

const DateControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/DateControl.vue'),
);

const EmailControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/EmailControl.vue'),
);

const NumberControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/NumberControl.vue'),
);

const RadioControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/RadioControl.vue'),
);

const RangeControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/RangeControl.vue'),
);

const SelectControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/SelectControl.vue'),
);

const TextareaControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/TextareaControl.vue'),
);

const TextControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/TextControl.vue'),
);

const loadComponent = (type: string) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'checkbox':
      return CheckboxControl;
    case 'date':
      return DateControl;
    case 'email':
      return EmailControl;
    case 'number':
      return NumberControl;
    case 'radio':
      return RadioControl;
    case 'range':
      return RangeControl;
    case 'select':
      return SelectControl;
    case 'textarea':
      return TextareaControl;
    case 'text':
      return TextControl;
    default:
      // TODO: show error component if type not supported
      break;
  }
};
```

#### Update 3

For my current setup I use vite as the build tool. The vite version I use is `2.9.5`. The vue version I use is `3.2.33` and the typescript version `4.6.3`.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown what data is in your case, it should be reproducible with static value instead of control.type . It's also loadComponent in one place and renderComponent in another, it's not confirmed they are the same

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for the comment. I added it to the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @Estus Flask for your help :)

So the problem was that I was trying to import it with the `@` alias. I changed my method to this:

```
const loadComponent = (type: string) =>
  defineAsyncComponent(
    () =>
      import(
        `./controls/${type[0].toUpperCase()}${type.substring(1)}Control.vue`
      ),
  );
```

This works now.

I don't know why in this case it is not working with the `@` alias, because it works when I use it in

```
const CheckboxControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/CheckboxControl.vue'),
);
```

Maybe someone has an explanation to this?

Comment: Interesting. Consider adding details about your setup. If you use Vite or Vue CLI, the version may matter.

Comment: I added it to the question :)

Answer (score 1):

`async` forces the function to return promise object, while a component is expected. It should be regular function:

```
const loadComponent = (type: string) => ...
```

It's `defineAsyncComponent` that handles underlying promise from `import`.

Comment: Already tried this. This gives an error: TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '@/components/editor/controls/CheckboxControl.vue'

Comment: Then that's it, you have the problem with import that is irrelevant to the thing you ask. You need to make sure that this module physically exists at this location and confirm that it works with both `import '@/components/editor/controls/CheckboxControl.vue'` and dynamic `import('@/components/editor/controls/CheckboxControl.vue')`. Then it should be expected that dynamic loader works. You said that "This works fine" but this error suggests the opposite thing

Comment: Thats the weird thing. When I use `const CheckboxControl = defineAsyncComponent(
  () => import('@/components/editor/controls/CheckboxControl.vue'),
);` it works. My current method to load the component is to return the component in a switch statement. I'll add it to the question

Comment: And it should stop working if you use a variable in import path. I guess that's specific to your setup then, which is unknown. It's a bundler that is responsible for how dynamic imports are handled. Also try regular string concat instead of template literal, it may be handled differently. Also what you do with a switch is not a really bad thing, for a limited set of components it's the way, can be improved by using a map of comps, `{ RangeControl: () => import('@/components/editor/controls/RangeControl.vue'), ...`

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Solved the issue :) I'll add my answer

Comment: Glad you solved it. Also calling defineAsync... once instead of doing this every time inside loadComponent may enable rendering optimizations, but I didn't benchmark this